# \renewcommand in tabular with \input

Tags: tables, macros

I have generated a bunch of files (exp1.tex-exp10.tex) for different experiments that define my variables by

```
\renewcommand{\minabserror}{\SI{0.01}{\meter}~}%
\renewcommand{\minabserrorat}{\SI{1.4}{\meter}~}%
```

In my float text, I can therefore write

```
\input{exp1}
The maximum rangee is \minabserror and occured at \minabserrorat.

\input{exp2}
The maximum range is \minabserror and occured at \minabserrorat.
```

, which will have the expected outcome.

When I do this in a table by

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
number    &    minerror    &     location     \\
\input{exp1}
1         &    \minabserror &     \minabserrorat  \\
\input{exp2}
2         &    \minabserror &     \minabserrorat  \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{my summary table}
\end{table}
```

, my "variables" are not updated.

Comment: `\renewcommand` isn't global, i.e. it's only redefined in the table cell and then 'swallowed' by the cell group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\gdef` instead of `\renewcommand`, which is not global and does not survive from one table cell (where is used with `\input`) to the next table cell. However, `\gdef` (global def) does survive this cell grouping.

Depending on the precise usage there are better strategies or setups, most likely.

`exp1.tex`

```
\gdef\minabserror{\SI{0.01}{\meter}~}%
\gdef\minabserrorat{\SI{1.4}{\meter}~}%
```

and `exp2.tex`

```
\gdef\minabserror{\SI{0.05}{\meter}~}%
\gdef\minabserrorat{\SI{1.9}{\meter}~}%
```

The main document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\providecommand{\minabserror}{}
\providecommand{\minabserrorat}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
number    &    minerror    &     location     \\
\input{exp1}
1         &    \minabserror &     \minabserrorat  \\
\input{exp2}
2         &    \minabserror &     \minabserrorat  \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{my summary table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for. any hints for better strategies?

Comment: @cschmol: No, not really. This would require more insight in your real document, i.e. what you really want to achieve.

Comment: ok, well anyway I don't have time for improvement now, submission in two days :/